# Change Display Resolution in Windows Embedded Compact 7.0

Tags: windows-ce, screen-resolution, windows-embedded-compact

I have successfully build a Windows Embedded Compact 7 OS using the Platform builder. It is deployed on the target device (a Single Board Computer) and is running as expected.

I need to add a feature to change the display resolution in WinEC 7.0 OS, just like it can be done from "Display settings" in Windows 10, or Windows 7 (See [Display resolution option_Win10.jpg](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m6670t2waNOpX9eKgwCnParkMiTHzZbi/view?usp=sharing)).

This feature is not available in the "Display Properties" of WinEC 7.0 OS (See snapshots - [Display Properties_Background.png](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yHHii3G6LyhYqxj9NjuV2SHJRjJ5IfRU/view?usp=sharing), [Display Properties_Appearance.png](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v_es7I-m3fig-9aOF9VSUo0NUIIuSYoY/view?usp=sharing), and [Display Properties_Backlight.png](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1grtUBwo4mN654Bmeh81qd8978GBefyQu/view?usp=sharing)).

I checked various catalog items. But I'm not able to identify the changes to be made in the OS build process so that this feature can be enabled.

Please guide as to how can this feature be enabled in WinEC 7.0. Thanks a lot!